# Detect if an external font has loaded using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-face, jquery-events

I'm loading 30 external fonts and I need to detect if the font has loaded to let the user know that the application is ready for use. How can I do that?

I know how to detect CSS, images and JS but not fonts. I've looked but I haven't found any tutorials on it. Just a note: I'm not using Google Font so I can't use their JavaScript plug-in.

All 30 fonts are loaded from an array using a jQuery plugin I found called [FontFace](http://www.sitepoint.com/the-fontface-jquery-plugin/) which I've modified a bit by adding the path of the font folder so that I just give it the names.

```
$.each(fonts, function (e, w) { //loopin thru the font names
    $('ul#fonts').append('<li data-size="' + parseInt(w.string) + '" data-font="' + w.name + '">' + w.name + '</li>')
    $('li[data-font="' + w.name + '"]').fontface({
        fontName: w.name, //the font name
        fileName: w.font, //and path
        fontSize: parseInt(w.string) + "px" //the font size
    }).fontApply({ //apply the font to this specific element
        fontFamily: w.name,
        fontSize: parseInt(w.string) + 'px'
    })
});
```

Comment: I had a look at the source and sorry, it just doesn't seem to be possible. I know it's probably that helpful but there's a really great service called [TypeKit](https://typekit.com/tour/library). It's not free but it supports loading callbacks: http://blog.typekit.com/2010/11/11/font-events-using-javascript-callbacks/

Comment: Ok...what if I detect if the page is loading anything, in this case the fonts in the background...that way I cn detect if the page has finished loading them??? can you help with that...

Comment: The problem is that they're being loaded via js _after_ the page load. The plugin just formats the fontface css and adds it to the page. The fonts could load quickly or slowly depending on the hosting server and the users connection. It's just not possible to tell, especially with such a large number of fonts.

Comment: Thank you for your time...am not a quiter so expect to here from me, I'll come up with a work around if I hv to, I will share it since I may not be the only one facing this problem...if I may ask, fonts are usually loaded into the cache?? is that right...just like JSON is, not sure actually about JSON too???

Comment: Yeah, fonts are cached so they'll load much faster after the first page load.

Comment: Thanks...that might help with the idea I have